# Android: Adding a Drawable to an existing LayerDrawable

Tags: java, android, drawable

I have a LayerDrawable which I construct with an array of Drawables of 5 Drawables.
Now let’s say in run-time I want to add another Drawable to my LayerDrawable, in response to an event. How do I do that without having to re-create the LayerDrawable, this time with an array of Drawables of 6 Drawables?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After LayerDrawable is created, new Drawables can not be added to it.

See the [source of LayerDrawable](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java): array of drawables is saved in `mLayerState.mChildren` and is only set in Constructor.

However, [`setDrawableByLayerId(..)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#setDrawableByLayerId%28int,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29) can be used to exchange an existing Drawable with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can addLayer since Api level >= 23:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.html#addLayer(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)